# How do I make a table row editable/delete using ejs?

Tags: html, node.js, ejs

I have a table body like so:

```
<tbody>
                    <%list.forEach(function(entry) {%>
                    <tr>
                        <td hidden><%=entry.movie_id%></td>
                        <td class="text-dark"><%=entry.movie_name%></td>
                        <td class="text-dark"><%=entry.rating%></td>
                        <td class="text-dark"><%=entry.cast%></td>
                        <td class="text-dark"><%=entry.genre%></td>
                        <td class="text-dark"><%=entry.release_date%></td>
                        <td id="edit-movie" class="text-dark">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">
                                Edit
                            </button>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-dark">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">
                                Delete
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <%});%>
                </tbody>
```

I want to open a form when I click the 'Edit' button, and that form should hold the value in the row and after submission should edit the row.

Answer (score 0):

- Wrap the table in a form
- Make the button a submit button
- Give the button a name (like `row`) and a value (`entry.movie_id`)
- Add some `if` tests to generate `<input>` elements instead of plain text if the `entry.movie_id` matches the submitted form data.

You'd probably get a better user experience if using client-side JS instead of EJS though.

Comment: I have to use ejs only. Can you please edit the answer to include the code for the solution. Also, the same for the delete feature.